Power BI Waterfall chart custom sort
I have a waterfall chart. x-axis is "Status" and y-axis is #Products -

Data consists of 31,776 rows which is represented in the rightmost bar. I want to custom sort the visual where the 2 extreme bars are swapped to convey that the starting point is 31,776 products and left with 26,931 products due to different "Status" removals as seen in middle bar.
I know the logic is to make those numbers negative, but I am not able to implement it.
